# Get the name of running docker container inside shell script

Tags: bash, docker

I am currently developing an application, in which I want to automate a testing process to speed up my development time. I use a postgres db container, and I then want to check that the preparation of the database is correct.

My process is currently as follows:

```sh
docker run -p 5432:5432 --env-file=".db_env" -d postgres # Start the postgres db
# Prep the db, do some other stuff 
# ...
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME psql -U postgres
```

Currently, I have to to `docker ps` to get the container name and then paste it and replace `CONTAINER_NAME`. The container is the only one running, so I am thinking I could easily find the container id or the container name automatically instead of using `docker ps` to manually retrieve it, but I don't know how. How do I do this using `bash`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The container id is being returned from the `docker run` command:

```
CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run -p 5432:5432 --env-file=".db_env" -d postgres)
```

Comment: This is more or less what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the name of your container with `docker run --name CONTAINER_NAME`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name

Comment: Thank you, but not really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can get its ID using:

```sh
docker ps -aqf "name=postgres"
```

If you're using Bash, you can do something like:

```sh
docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf "name=postgres") psql -U postgres
```

Comment: Thank you! This did not work however, but almost! :) Posting an answer that answers my question properly above :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I took use of @mrcl's answer, from which I developed a complete answer. Thank you for that @mrcl!

```sh
CONTAINER_ID=$(docker run -p 5432:5432 --env-file=".db_env" -d postgres)
# Do some other stuff
# ...
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID psql -U postgres
```